# Problem in static site generated and anchor links

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

In a Nuxt 2 (^2.15.8) project with static site generation, there is in the pages folder a component in a file named *subroute.ts*

This component has some basic Vue implementation and the template has a plain HTML anchor link:

```html
<a
  class="link link--menu link--menu-icon text-uppercase"
  href="#about"
  title="Sobre a Farmtech Gestão"
  @click="close"
> Sobre a Farmtech Gestão
</a>
```

In development mode this works like a charm.

When the site is generated (*nuxt generate*), Nuxt generates a folder with an index.html file:

[image]

Then I can run http-server dist to serve the static files:

[image]

If I access the index.html (http://127.0.0.1:8080/subroute/index.html), when the user clicks on link, the url changes to http://127.0.0.1:8080/subroute/index.html#about but for some reason it seems Nuxt is trying to route this url and then, it fails:

[image]

The weird thing is that if I access it without the index.html, everything works as expected.
I noticed that when using index.html in the url, the link element has these events added to it:
[image]

but without index.html, there are a lot more:
[image]

It seems Nuxt fails to deal with the index.html in the url, it expects to have only the folder's name in it. And the problem is that, in my project, due to some infrastructures exigences, the shared url from the website will have to be shared with index.html

What could be happening?